# Capybara visit is acting odd

Tags: ruby, https, capybara

I'm getting a weird issue with the visit command.

It feels like it's getting hung up on a secure (https://) site.

When I have

```
When /^I access a company page$/ do
   visit('https://www.yahoo.com/yahoo')
end

When /^I access the Terms of Use Page$/ do
   visit('https://www.yahoo.com/terms-of-use')
end

When /^I access the Privacy Policy Page$/ do
   visit('https://www.yahoo.com/privacy')
end
```

I resolve to the first site called,  subsequent visits display the new url in the browser but keeps resolving to the first site.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you sure these are valid locations?  The first 2 don't exist for my browser, and all of them redirect to the non-secure site (http:)

Comment: Those were abstracts.  The actual sites were removed.

Comment: Does actual site have a valid certificate? Is there basic auth there?

Comment: I don't have such issues with [this code](http://pastebin.com/GkLUjedy)